# Good resources on InstallScript

Tags: installscript

Can anyone recommend any resources on the web for learning installscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:
http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield20helplib/installshield20helplib.htm

Updated the broken link. Unfortunately Installshield regularly change their help resource paths.

Answer (score 3):

Note that on the InstallShield DVD media is a .PDF file (`InstallShieldInstallScript.pdf`) that is the most comprehensive InstallScript resource -- as of IS 2009, it's 1626 pages!!!

Granted, this is not "on the web" as you asked, but it is electronic, and free, assuming you have a licensed copy of InstallShield.

Hope that helps.